# How do I swap out a COM dll

Tags: c#, .net, delphi, dll

I have a Windows Service written in ***Delphi***, which utilities a ***dll***, also written in ***Delphi***. This ***dll*** uses a ***.Net dll*** to handle comm's.

All of these pre-date my time at the company, and no source is available for any of it.
The ***.Net dll***  contains a url to a web service, which needs to change. I’ve de-compiled the ***.Net dll*** , changed the brand and recompiled, but swapping out the old file for this new one results in the error

‘OLE error 80131040’

I’ve spent a lot of time Googling/researching this error but since I don’t have the source for the Delphi part, the answers I found were of no use.

Things I know:

•   To prove the decompile/recompile process, I took the original, dll and used that as a test. Once recompiled it functioned perfectly.

•   The only thing changed in the ‘modified’ dll  is the URL of the web service.

•   I ran Process Monitor against the service whilst using it, and identified several references in the registry (CLSID).

•   I have generated a registry ‘merge’ file using Regasm, and applied this. All old references were replaced as far as I can see, but now my error has changed to ‘Class not registered’.

•   Re-running the process monitor with these changes showed the service is STILL trying to get the original registry entry.

•   I have scoured the registry for this entry (673DED65-BE57-36AF-AE8F-5BD418F1596E) and found nothing. I also let Agent Ransack loose doing a content search, which produced no results after 6 hours of searching.

•   I know from archived versions of the dlls that these have been swapped out multiple times without the actual service ever being altered; therefore I can’t see how the registry key can be coded in to that program.

•   I have checked the GAC and the assembly is not listed in there, even on the working version.

•   I have tried adding to the GAC, but get an error about the assembly not being strongly named, so I don't think it's ever been in there?

So the question is, how is the service STILL getting a registry key that doesn't exist and isn't detailed anywhere as far as I can see? Have I missed a vital step somewhere?

Comment: The error you are getting means: "The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference".  The GAC contains the old information, but you replaced the file, so the manifest does not match the file anymore.

Comment: If my reading is correct, the GAC is basically at \Windows\Assembly? I already checked there and it isn't listed. I tried adding the new dll and got an error about it not being strongly named. I've edited above to include this in 'thing's I know' Thanks

Comment: What is you o.s. and architecture? And try assembly registration with /codebase switch.

Comment: Windows Server 2003, 32bit. I'll try the codebase switch in the morning, Thanks.

Comment: Ok the codebase switch didn't work, but did lead me down a new trail. My problem is the original DLL is strongly named and this information hasn't carried to the de-compiled version. I've compared various archived versions and they always have the same key and token, my new one is different. I don't have the original .snk... Is there anyway I can recreate it with the information available through the sn tool, or am i now looking at a no-hope?